# ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module on GCP

Tags: python, django, postgresql, google-app-engine

Currently I'm trying to launch my django web app to GCP by following this doc:
[here](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine)

FYI: I'm using Django 1.9 and Python 2.7

After deploying the app using `gcloud app deploy` I checked my App Dashboard and saw these errors:

1) `ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named psycopg2`

2) `RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant`

After doing some research on how to fix the psycopg2 error I found a few answers [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql-postgres).

But it was to no avail.

Here is what's inside my requirements.txt

```
psycopg2==2.7.1
Flask==0.12
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.2
gunicorn==19.7.0
PyMySQL==0.7.10
django==1.9
django-imagekit
pillow
pyexcel
pyexcel_xls
django_excel
xlsxwriter
python-dateutil
django-mail-templated
djangorestframework
django-cors-headers
django-extra-fields
pytz
numpy
reportlab
xhtml2pdf
html5lib==1.0b8
pypdf
```

and this is what's inside my app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
- url: .*
  script: root.wsgi.application

libraries:
- name: MySQLdb 
  version: 1.2.5
- name: django 
  version: 1.9

env_variables:
    # Replace user, password, database, and instance connection name with the values obtained
    # when configuring your Cloud SQL instance.
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI: >-
      postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:db_password@/DATABASE?host=/cloudsql/db:location:instance

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances:db:location:instance


skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?#.*#$
- ^(.*/)?.*~$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\..*$
- ^env/.*$
```

and finally by db settings on settings.py

```
# [START db_setup]
if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine'):
    # Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
    # the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/db_name:location:instance_name',
            'NAME': 'db_name',
            'USER': 'user_name',
            'PASSWORD': 'db_password',
        }
    }
else:
    from .local_settings import *
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': name,
            'USER': user,
            'PASSWORD': password,
            'HOST' : host,
            'PORT' : '',
        }
    }
    # [END db_setup]
```

Solutions to this problem is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does your `requirements.txt` file look like?

Comment: @themanatuf I've edited my post to include my requirements.txt and app.yaml.

Comment: @themanatuf I added also an appengine_config.py but it's giving me this error

"ValueError: virtualenv: cannot access lib: No such virtualenv or site directory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got the problem fixed about my postgreSQL. As it turns out, since I was using the Standard App Engine environment it didn't support third-party applications like postgreSQL. So I had to switch to the Flex environment which was very easy. I just changed my app.yaml to this:

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT myproject.wsgi

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: project:location:instance_name

runtime_config:
  python_version: 2

# [END runtime]

# Google App Engine limits application deployments to 10,000 uploaded files per
# version. The skip_files section allows us to skip virtual environment files
# to meet this requirement. The first 5 are the default regular expressions to
# skip, while the last one is for all env/ files.
skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?#.*#$
- ^(.*/)?.*~$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\..*$
- ^env/.*$
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was fixed by doing a pip install psycopg2